# Pentaho - XPath Select all children with specific parent

Tags: xml, xpath, pentaho, kettle

I'm using Pentaho 'Get data from XML'.

I want to select all children `<price>` whose parent `<book>` name is `'1.1'`.

```
<bookstore>
  <book name = '1.1'>
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <price>29.99</price>
    <price>39.99</price>
    <price>59.99</price>
  </book>

  <book name = '1.2'>
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

The configuration I put with the step are this:

[image: Configuration Step Content]

[image: Configuration Step Fields]

And the result I got are the following:

[image: Result]

If I change the 'Loop Xpath' in Content like: `/bookstore/book/price` I got 4 rows of the same first price (29.99).

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of things you did, this is terribly hard to read. Post the XPaths and results as text.

Answer (score 1):

In "Content" you set the "loop XPath" to `/bookstore/book`, so you will end up with a loop over (in this example) two items - the one you want, and the other one.

In "Fields" you normally set up the data fields to be extracted from each of those items. Therefore the XPath should be relative here.

But you used `//book[@name = '1.1']/price`, which is an absolute path. It selects three items, of which Pentaho can only take the first one to populate a field. That's why you get `29.99` two times.

What to do? It's always the same approach.

To get general information on all books:

- Select the right items in the "loop" part: `//book`
- Select the field values using relative paths: `./price[1]` and probably `./title`

To get general information on one specific book:

- Select the right item in the "loop" part: `//book[@name = '1.1']`
- Select the field values using relative paths: `./price[1]` and probably `./title`

To get prices of one specific book:

- Select the right items in the "loop" part: `//book[@name = '1.1']/price`
- Select the field values using relative paths: `./text()` (or simply `.`)

Answer (score 0):

Try `/bookstore/book[@name='1.1']/*`

Comment: This would also select the `title` element.

Comment: Then select `price` instead of `*`.

Comment: I tried with /bookstore/book[@name='1.1']/* in the Content - Loop Xpath, and then with relative path get all the price and discount nodes, but it doesn't work.. In relative path I put several (./price or ../price or just price)
I never work with xPath and it's a little bit confused :( 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Tomalak! It's work. I tried to put `/bookstore/book[@name='1.1']/*` Wasmachien but in pentaho doesn't work, but thanks for the answer!

The key was, ***"In "Fields" you normally set up the data fields to be extracted from each of those items. Therefore the XPath should be relative here."***

Now I tried to select all specifed children node with `//book[@name = '1.1']`, but if in the parent book have i.e. **'price' and 'discount'** too. Tried with `.` or `price` in the relative paths doesn't works, it's return just the first child again. 
It's possible to use `//book[@name = '1.1']` and get all the children with their respective nodes?

Thanks